# Not able to access env variables in Remix, even in a server file

Tags: typescript, remix, remix.run, shopify-hydrogen

I was using Shopify's version of Remix and ran into an issue where I tried to access an API key to be used in a newsletter signup form. However, I cannot access my env variables due to the error `process is not defined.`

app/env/env.server.ts:

```
import {ZodFormattedError} from 'zod';

const serverSchema = z.object({
  KLAVIYO_API_KEY: z.string(),
  KLAVIYO_GLOBAL_LIST_ID: z.string(),
  KLAVIYO_API_VERSION: z.string(),
})

const _serverEnv = serverSchema.safeParse(process.env);

const formatErrors = (errors: ZodFormattedError<Map<string, string>, string>) =>
  Object.entries(errors)
    .map(([name, value]) => {
      if (value && '_errors' in value)
        return `${name}: ${value._errors.join(', ')}\n`;
    })
    .filter(Boolean);

if (_serverEnv.success === false) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.error(
    '❌ Invalid environment variables:\n',
    ...formatErrors(_serverEnv.error.format()),
  );

  throw new Error('Invalid environment variables');
}

export const env = {..._serverEnv.data};
```

routes/newsletter/subscribe.tsx:

```
import {ActionArgs, json} from '@shopify/remix-oxygen';
import { env } from '../../env/env.server';

export async function action({request}: ActionArgs) {
  const email = (await request.formData()).get('email')?.toString() ?? '';
  try {
    const res = await subscribeToKlaviyoList(email);

    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    return json({error: error.message, ok: false});
  }
}



export async function subscribeToKlaviyoList(
  email: string,
  source = 'Home Page Footer',
) {
  const API_KEY = env.KLAVIYO_API_VERSION;
  const API_VERSION = env.KLAVIYO_API_VERSION;
  const LIST_ID = env.KLAVIYO_GLOBAL_LIST_ID;

  return await fetch(
    'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/profile-subscription-bulk-create-jobs/',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        revision: API_VERSION ?? '2023-01-24',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Klaviyo-API-Key ${API_KEY}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        data: {
          type: 'profile-subscription-bulk-create-job',
          attributes: {
            list_id: LIST_ID,
            custom_source: source,
            subscriptions: [
              {
                channels: {email: ['MARKETING']},
                email,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      }),
    },
  );
}
```

I've followed along with [this](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/hooks/use-fetcher) example from Remix and [this](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/blob/9b46b9025f534fc8e7bf4c4839ab46092505706e/examples/newsletter-signup/app/routes/newsletter.tsx) GitHub repo, but in both instances, they either aren't using env variables or the API key is hard coded. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you hosting your app? Which adapter are you using? Are you using Shopify Oxygen?

Comment: @Kiliman I'm just running this locally, and even then, it's throwing that error. I will be deploying to Oxygen, though.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the env variables to the `Env` type in the remix.env.d.ts file. So I solved this by doing the following:

```
interface Env extends z.infer<typeof serverSchema> {
    SESSION_SECRET: string;
    PUBLIC_STOREFRONT_API_TOKEN: string;
    PRIVATE_STOREFRONT_API_TOKEN: string;
    PUBLIC_STOREFRONT_API_VERSION: string;
    PUBLIC_STORE_DOMAIN: string;
    PUBLIC_STOREFRONT_ID: string;
  }
```

And then calling the env variable as shown:

```
export async function action({context, request}: ActionArgs) {
  const email = (await request.formData()).get('email')?.toString() ?? '';
  try {
    await subscribeToKlaviyoList(context.env, email);
    return json({error: null, ok: true});
  } catch (error) {
    return json({error: error.message, ok: false});
  }
}

export async function subscribeToKlaviyoList(
  env: Env,
  email: string,
  source = 'Home Page Footer',
) {
  const API_KEY = env.KLAVIYO_API_KEY;
  const API_VERSION = env.KLAVIYO_API_VERSION;
  const LIST_ID = env.KLAVIYO_GLOBAL_LIST_ID;

  return await fetch(
    'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/profile-subscription-bulk-create-jobs/',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        revision: API_VERSION ?? '2023-01-24',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Klaviyo-API-Key ${API_KEY}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        data: {
          type: 'profile-subscription-bulk-create-job',
          attributes: {
            list_id: LIST_ID,
            custom_source: source,
            subscriptions: [
              {
                channels: {email: ['MARKETING']},
                email,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      }),
    },
  );
}
```

Hopefully, we don't need to use context in the future.